# .NET Core with windows authentication angular app gets error

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, windows-authentication

I wrote a service in .NET Core Web API, I use windows authentication=true because I need the details of the current user. But when

```
 "windowsAuthentication": true,
 "anonymousAuthentication": false,
```

my angular app can't reach the service and it returns unauthorize error:
401 Unauthorized for options and in the console:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44343/api/smooss' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS

When I set `"anonymousAuthentication": true` it does work but then i don't have the details of the user

my code looks like that:

client:

```
public CheckISAuthorized() {
    
    const  requestOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Authorization': "my-request-token",
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        })
    };
      
    return this.http.get(`${baseUrl}smooss`,requestOptions );
}}
```

I have interceptor that adds `withCredentials=true`:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
   debugger;
   request = request.clone({
       withCredentials: true
        
   });

    return next.handle(request);
}
```

in server:

startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContextPool<SMOOSSContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SmoosDB")));
          
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddScoped<ISmooseRepository, SmoosRepository>();
    services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials();
    }));

           
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Smoos", Version = "v1" });
    });
    services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, AppSmoossRequirement>();
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AppSmooss", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new AppSmoossRequirement()));
    });
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
   
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)

{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Smoos v1"));
    }
    
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseAuthorization();
   
  }
```

in controller:

```
[EnableCors("MyPolicy")]
     [Authorize(Policy = "AppSmooss")]
    [Route("api/smooss")]
    [ApiController]
    public class SmoossApi : ControllerBase
```

this is the method:

```
[HttpGet]

public async Task<List<Smooss>> Get()
{ 
    return await SmoosRepository.GetFlights();
}
```

Comment: Hi @miri l. , I think you need check this github issue:https://github.com/aspnet/CORS/issues/60

Answer (score 1):

so finally I found the solution thanks to
Rena's comment about this post:
github.com/aspnet/CORS/issues/60
the problem is that the options call from the browser is not sent with the credentials and thats why its unauthorized.
the solution is to add a middleWare to handle options request
and to allow both windows and anonymous authentication so that options request will succeed

the middleWare:

```
 public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Method != "OPTIONS" && 
       !context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            return; //Stop pipeline and return immediately.
        }
        await _next(context);
    }
```

in launchSettings.json:

```
"iisSettings": {
"windowsAuthentication": true,
"anonymousAuthentication": true ,
```

I also had to remove the authorization header in my client side:

```
      const  requestOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
//this line  is not needed
      // 'Authorization': "my-request-token",
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
      };
```